# ¿Como hacer para que container ocupe 100% del height de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

El caso es que tengo este codigo

```
 ...
 <body>

   <div class="container">
    ...
   </div>

 </body>
 ...
```

Dentro del container tengo un formulario de login que ocupa mas o menos la mitad del height de la pantalla y yo con este codigo:

```
.container {
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hago que el container me ocupa todo el height del navegador aunque los  elementos no lo ocupen todo.

Hasta aqui todo bien, pero cuando paso a una pagina de registro esta es mas larga (tiene mas contenido, mas elementos) y ocupa mas del 100% del height del navegador y cuando bajo con el scroll el container (que esta de color gris) se queda hasta cierto punto y el "background: gray;" se queda hasta cierto punto. Osea que el color gris ocupa el 100% del height y cuando hay necesidad de scroll, de ahi para abajo no hay color gris. Espero darme a enterder.

Comment: Prueba a utilizar `.container{min-height: 100vh;}`

Comment: Eso es lo que estaba buscando. A investigar sobre esa propiedad, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola amigo eso se debe a que el height 100% ocupa el 100% de la altura al cargar tu web al dar scroll eso se queda donde se cargo la web nada mas.

```
   <body> 
          <div class="container"> 
           ... 
          </div> 
     </body>
```

En el css agregas min-height para que a medida que des scroll el gris se 
mueva espero te sirva.

```
      .container { 
         background: gray; 
         min-height: 100vh; 
        }
```